# What is the standard install location for something like Groovy on OS X?

Tags: macos, groovy, installation

What is the standard install location for something like Groovy on OS X?  I used `/opt`, but was wondering what others use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Groovy community has started using [**GVM the Groovy enVironment Manager**](http://gvmtool.net/). Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have an `Applications` folder in my home folder where I copied the expanded groovy binary folders to, then create a symlink (just named `groovy`) to this folder (so I can easily switch versions). Then I added `~/Applications/groovy/bin` to my path.

on my new machines,  I now use gvm as Arturo says